# Euler's Theorem on infiniteness of primes in a specific arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory

**Dirichlet's theorem:** *given positive integers $a,d$ which are relatively prime, there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression*
$$a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,\cdots $$

It is mentioned on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#History) that Euler had proved a special case of this- with $a=1$; i.e. there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression 
$$1,1+d,1+2d,1+3d,\cdots.$$

**Q.** Is the proof of this special case (Euler's theorem) simpler than that of Dirichlets' theorem?

Comment: it does not say Euler proved it. It says an elementary proof using cyclotomic extensions is in the book by Neukirch. I believe it is also given or summarized, in an expository article by Keith Conrad. See if I can find that.

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf